# Could an animal have a developed Broca's area but no Wernicke's area?

Tags: brain, intelligence, communication

Broca's area's function is for speech production, specifically, the control of muscular movement for speech, and Wernicke's area's function is the comprehend language or *communication*, Communication being the keyword here. Communication includes the physical gestures and movement of an organism such as the Waggle Dance of honey bees.

Would this mean that honeybees (although they have very small brains) wouldn't have Broca's area as they cannot produce speech but have a slightly developed Wernicke's area?

Comment: These are terms used for the very particular organization of human cortex. No animal except humans has a Broca's area or a Wernicke's area. I would leave those words out of the question.

Comment: Remember that you're asking about a creature that has had a radically different evolutionary pathway from humans. Remember also  the network-wide requirement to *show your research* when asking a question. Perhaps start by looking at the [different structures and their functions](https://invbrain.neuroinf.jp/modules/htmldocs/IVBPF/Bee/Bee_brain.html) in apes melifera, comparing them with the human brain, then take the [tour], read-up in the [help] especially about [ask], then you can [edit]  your question into shape.

Comment: Thank you, will do